# Making Vibrate iPhone when switch on a toggle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, theos, tweak

I'm searching a way to add a vibration when you switch on a toggle in the PrefernceBundle of my tweak.

This is a part of my code:

```
    #define PLIST_PATH @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/MyTweak.plist"

inline bool GetPrefBool(NSString *key)
{
return [[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:PLIST_PATH] valueForKey:key] boolValue];
}

%hook Config
- (void)setURL:(NSString *)fp8 {
if(GetPrefBool(@"kPatch")) {
fp8 = @"http://abcdef.com";
%orig(fp8);
}
return %orig;
}
%end
```

I want to do when you switch on the "kPatch" toggle, the device vibrate.

I know I need to use this:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

and import this:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```

But I don't know how use them with my code.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

Just create a function that let the device vibrate and connect it to the IBOutlet

```
ViewController.h 

-(IBAction)Vibrate; 

ViewController.m 

#import "ViewController.h" 
#import "AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h" 

@implementation ViewController 

-(IBAction)Vibrate
{ 
   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate); 
}
```

Comment: But with this when the iPhone will vibrate? I want do it when you enable the toggle

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the same thing which you said, Just import the class and write that function where you want vibration.

Comment: you want vibration on button? if yes, apply this method where u want, i already try this and it's works fine in my case.

Comment: i was try this with uibutton

Comment: I just import the class in my ViewController.h file AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h and write AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) on button click method, whenever i click on that button my iPhone is Vibrate.